# image is not coming on rotating the screen orientation either from vertical to horizontal or vice versa?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

i selected one image from the SD card by using the intent and after selecting the image i displayed that image in an image viewer and it is showing but when i am rotating my screen the selected image is not coming,help me??

i used the intent for browsing the screen-

```
public void onClick(View v) {   
   Intent intent = new Intent();     
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);    
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Key Picture"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
}
```

and  for showing it

```
if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {        
   mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
   path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); 
   if (path == null) {
      path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); 
   }
   if (path != null) {
      bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
   }
}
preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during a screen rotation the Android System will recreate your activity to enable your layout to adapt to the new screen configuration.

If the image is disappearing after you rotate the screen there are two ways to solve this problem.

First and easiest way: Add the following to the declaration of your activity in your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

this will tell the Android System to not recreate your activity during the screen rotation.

The other way would be to save the path to the image in the [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) method in your activity and reload the image after the recreation of the activity. This will help you to solve errors in wich your activity gets killed because of memory problems (for example if your app is running and somebody calls). After this the same recreation process should be used.

Regardless of which way you are choosing have a good look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) Documentation. Understanding this is key to understand how the whole Android System is working.

Comment: please tell me that where to mention this line in manifest  and also tell me that how we can save the path also please??

Comment: but i used your suggestion but it also restarting the activity

Answer (score 0):

you can add some lines in android manifest as onsurfacechange="orientation" so when will you  change your screen rotation than nothing will be happen so your image will be like as it was previous